# I need a loop to delete rows according to timestamp difference in R

Tags: r

I am working on a project where I have few million rows and each contains timestamp. Each row also includes the unique ID of that event. Current condition is that rows with the same event ID can have timestamp difference of 1 minute (there cant be two events with delta timestamp less than 1minute).

What I want to simulate is the situation which would happen if minimal timestamp difference would be 3 minutes.

```
    TIME_STAMP              PREV_TIME_STAMP      Unique ID 
06-27-2021 07:07:22       06-27-2021 06:30:00         1 
06-27-2021 07:18:26       06-27-2021 07:07:22         1 
06-27-2021 07:20:26       06-27-2021 07:18:26         1 
06-27-2021 07:22:26       06-27-2021 07:20:26         1 
06-27-2021 07:22:26       06-27-2021 07:22:26         1 
06-27-2021 15:18:05       06-27-2021 15:11:00         2 
06-27-2021 15:19:05       06-27-2021 15:18:05         2 
06-27-2021 12:31:37       06-27-2021 12:30:00         2 
06-27-2021 12:35:05       06-27-2021 12:30:00         2
```

The problem is that I cant only make new column with difference between messages, I do need a loop for this - why? see below:

From the table the situation is following:

- First row is accepted as the delta is 37 minutes
- Second row is    accepted as the delta is 11 minutes
- Third row **IS NOT ACCEPTED** as    the delta is 1.5 minutes
- Fourth row **IS ACCEPTED** as the previous    event is **NOT**
  07:20:26, it is 07:18:26 (row three is deleted so it is not considered!). So delta time for 4th row is 07:22:26 - 07:18:26 = 4 minutes > 3 minutes which means accepted

So there is need to define a referent timestamp (it is the previous ACCEPTED time), and delta between new time and previous time WHICH IS ACCEPTED has to be 3 minutes or higher.

I hope that I managed to explain it well enough. If not, please answer and I will provide as much as information I can.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
df <- data.frame(TIME_STAMP = as.POSIXct(strptime(
  c("06-27-2021 07:07:22", 
    "06-27-2021 07:18:26",
    "06-27-2021 07:20:26",
    "06-27-2021 07:22:26",
    "06-27-2021 07:22:26",
    "06-27-2021 15:18:05",
    "06-27-2021 15:19:05",
    "06-27-2021 12:31:37",
    "06-27-2021 12:35:05"), "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")),
  PREV_TIME_STAMP = as.POSIXct(strptime(
    c("06-27-2021 06:30:00",
      "06-27-2021 07:07:22",
      "06-27-2021 07:18:26",
      "06-27-2021 07:20:26",
      "06-27-2021 07:22:26",
      "06-27-2021 15:11:00",
      "06-27-2021 15:18:05",
      "06-27-2021 12:30:00",
      "06-27-2021 12:30:00"), "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")),
  ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2))
```

Comment: Please provide the data above in a usable format, e.g. by using `dput()`.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this forum. What do you mean by "usable format"? Why my data is not usable?

Comment: It's not usable because we can't copy and paste your data in an R script to help. Please, use `dput()` to export a reproducible example of your data

Comment: for ID=2, why are the last 2 entries of PREV_TIME_STAMP the same and not just lagged values of TIME_STAMP?

Answer (score 5):

First you should rearrange the data and remove the redundancy of your two time columns:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("    TIME_STAMP,           Unique ID 
            06-27-2021 06:30:00,       1 
            06-27-2021 07:07:22,       1 
            06-27-2021 07:18:26,       1 
            06-27-2021 07:20:26,       1 
            06-27-2021 07:22:26,       1 
            06-27-2021 07:22:26,       1 
            06-27-2021 15:11:00,       2
            06-27-2021 15:18:05,       2 
            06-27-2021 15:19:05,       2 
            06-27-2021 12:31:37,       2 
            06-27-2021 12:35:05,       2")
```

Then you can do this easily with Rcpp:

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction(
  'LogicalVector deleteRow(const NumericVector x) {
     const double n = x.size();
     double j = 0;
     LogicalVector res = LogicalVector(n);
     for (double i = 1; i < n; i++) {
       if (x(i) - x(j) < 180) {
         res[i] = true;
       } else {
         j = i;
       }
     }

  return res;
  }')

DT[, TIME_STAMP := as.POSIXct(TIME_STAMP, format = "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S", tz = "GMT")]
setkey(DT, `Unique ID`, TIME_STAMP) #ensure sorting
DT[, delete := deleteRow(TIME_STAMP), by = `Unique ID`]
#             TIME_STAMP Unique ID delete
# 1: 2021-06-27 06:30:00         1  FALSE
# 2: 2021-06-27 07:07:22         1  FALSE
# 3: 2021-06-27 07:18:26         1  FALSE
# 4: 2021-06-27 07:20:26         1   TRUE
# 5: 2021-06-27 07:22:26         1  FALSE
# 6: 2021-06-27 07:22:26         1   TRUE
# 7: 2021-06-27 12:31:37         2  FALSE
# 8: 2021-06-27 12:35:05         2  FALSE
# 9: 2021-06-27 15:11:00         2  FALSE
#10: 2021-06-27 15:18:05         2  FALSE
#11: 2021-06-27 15:19:05         2   TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done iteratively. The idea is to identify points that *must* be included, use these to remove points that *can't* be included and to repeat until done.

Here's some simple data, not time stamps but integers (timestamps are easily converted to integer via `as.integer()`), supposing that we are interested in a 'width' of 10 -- starts less than 10 units apart are to be filtered.

```
set.seed(123)
start <- sort(sample(100, 10))
width <- 10
```

We write a function to take the start and  width

```
filter1 <- function(start, width) {
```

Construct intervals for each start

```
    end <- start + width - 1L                       # closed interval
```

figure out how to put the start and end in order, and remember which start event corresponds to the ordering

```
    o <- order(c(start, end))
    is_start <- rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), each = length(start))[o]
```

encode start events as 1, end events as -1, and calculate the 'coverage', the number of events that are open

```
    event <- rep(c(1, -1), each = length(start))[o] # 1 == open, -1 == close
    cvg <- cumsum(event)                            # number of open intervals
```

We know for sure that we want to keep start events where the coverage increments to 1, so keep those

```
    must <- (event == 1 & cvg == 1)[is_start]
    open <- start[must]                                # non-overlapping events
```

and find the event that are NOT in those intervals

```
    close <- end[must] + 1L
    might <- findInterval(start, sort(c(open, close))) %% 2 == 0
```

return the values that we know to be good, and that we have not yet excluded

```
    must | might                        # best guess, so far
}
```

The complete function is

```
filter1 <- function(start, width) {
    end <- start + width - 1L                       # closed interval
    o <- order(c(start, end))
    is_start <- rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), each = length(start))[o]

    event <- rep(c(1, -1), each = length(start))[o] # 1 == open, -1 == close
    cvg <- cumsum(event)                            # number of open intervals
    must <- (event == 1 & cvg == 1)[is_start]

    open <- start[must]                             # non-overlapping events
    close <- end[must] + 1L
    might <- findInterval(start, sort(c(open, close))) %% 2 == 0

    must | might
}
```

We now have a shortened vector of possible candidates; we iterate until the length of candidates does not change

```
filter_all <- function(start, width) {
    idx <- !logical(length(start))
    repeat {
        idx0 <- filter1(start[idx], width)
        if (sum(idx0)  == sum(idx))
            break
        idx[idx] <- idx0
    }
    idx
}
```

in action:

```
> set.seed(123)
> (start <- sort(sample(100, 10)))
 [1]  5 29 41 42 50 51 79 83 86 91
> keep <- filter_all(start, 10)
> start[keep]
[1]  5 29 41 51 79 91
```

This might not be correct (but can be made so) in the case where intervals end and start at the same location. Worst-case performance would be linear in the number of starts (when the end of one interval exactly overlaps the start of another, width units along), but seems like it will often be approximately logarithmic.

This can be applied to groups using data.table, or base R functions such as `ave()`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that it is just typo in last 2 entries of PREV_TIME_STAMP for ID=2, here is another method using `Reduce` using Ronald's dataset.

```
   #sort by TIME_STAMP to make sure older entries come up first
DT[order(TIME_STAMP), 
    #convert numeric to POSIX
    as.POSIXct(
        #get a distinct set of timestamp that is greater than 3 minutes
        unique(
            #use curr if more than 3 mins from prev, else keep the prev value
            Reduce(function(x,y) if(as.double(y-x,units="mins") >= 3) y else x, 
                  TIME_STAMP, 
                  accumulate=TRUE)
            ),
        origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT"), 
    by=`Unique ID`]
```

---

edit: share timings. tl;dr Roland method is way faster

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0L)
M <- 2e6
nIDs <- M/1e3
DT <- data.table(
    ID=sample(nIDs, M, replace=TRUE),
    TIME_STAMP=as.POSIXct(as.numeric(Sys.time())+sample(60*(0:4), M, replace=TRUE), origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT"))
setorder(DT, ID, TIME_STAMP)
DT2 <- copy(DT)

library(Rcpp)
cppFunction(
    'LogicalVector deleteRow(const NumericVector x) {
     const double n = x.size();
     double j = 0;
     LogicalVector res = LogicalVector(n);
     for (double i = 1; i < n; i++) {
       if (x(i) - x(j) < 180) {
         res[i] = true;
       } else {
         j = i;
       }
     }

  return res;
  }')

filter1 <- function(start, width) {
    end <- start + width - 1L                       # closed interval
    o <- order(c(start, end))
    is_start <- rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), each = length(start))[o]

    event <- rep(c(1, -1), each = length(start))[o] # 1 == open, -1 == close
    cvg <- cumsum(event)                            # number of open intervals
    must <- (event == 1 & cvg == 1)[is_start]

    open <- start[must]                             # non-overlapping events
    close <- end[must] + 1L
    might <- findInterval(start, sort(c(open, close))) %% 2 == 0

    must | might
}

filter_all <- function(start, width) {
    idx <- !logical(length(start))
    repeat {
        idx0 <- filter1(start[idx], width)
        if (sum(idx0)  == sum(idx))
            break
        idx[idx] <- idx0
    }
    idx
}

basemtd <- function() {
    DT[, filter_all(TIME_STAMP, 3), by=ID]
}

rcppmtd <- function() {    
    DT[, delete := deleteRow(TIME_STAMP), by=ID]
}

dtmtd2 <- function() {
    DT2[, 
        as.POSIXct(
            unique(
                Reduce(function(x,y) if(as.double(y-x,units="mins") >= 3) y else x, 
                      TIME_STAMP, 
                      accumulate=TRUE)
                ),
            origin="1970-01-01", tz="GMT"), 
        by=ID]
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(basemtd(), rcppmtd(), dtmtd2(), times=3L)
```

timings:

```
Unit: milliseconds
      expr         min           lq                mean      median                    uq         max neval
 basemtd()   3579.0786   3601.19295   3608.667733333333   3623.3073   3623.46230000000014   3623.6173     3
 rcppmtd()     37.0085     37.53650     39.001500000000     38.0645     39.99800000000000     41.9315     3
  dtmtd2() 210238.1842 210901.39020 211303.247133333323 211564.5962 211835.77860000001965 212106.9610     3
```

Comment: Neat! In `basemtd()` width should be 180 (check using `identical()`). I think you should time only the functions, not data.table operations, on the sorted time stamps; for me `filter_all()` is about 15x slower than `deleteRow()` (excluding the time to learn C++ and Rcpp!)

Comment: @MartinMorgan do you mean `ave(DT$TIME_STAMP, DT$ID, filter_all)`? let me update the timings with this

Comment: I meant `x = sort(DT$TIME_STAMP); microbenchmark(filter_all(x, 180), deletRows(x), ...)` so that one is measuring the performance of the different implementations, rather than other aspects unrelated to the problem.