# Enforce minimum interval between adjacent events data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset with assessments and dates for participants. Participants are not to be assessed for a certain period after each event, so I need to ignore additional assessments during that period.

Currently I've achieved this with a bit of a hacky loop, but there's looping and comparisons, and my actual dataset has hundreds of thousands of rows. I'm wondering if anyone can think up a more 'pure' data.table solution.

```
library(data.table)
exclusionPeriod = 5

dt = data.table(id = c('a','a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c','c'),
                start = c(1, 2, 7, 9, 1, 8, 12, 2, 4, 5, 8))

modelOut = data.table(id = c('a','a','b','b','c','c'),
                      start = c(1, 7, 1, 8, 2, 8))

print(dt)
print(modelOut)

dt[,diff := c(0, diff(start)), by = id]    
dt[,csum := cumsum(diff), by = id]

maxIts = 100
its = 0
while (nrow(dt[csum>exclusionPeriod]) & its < maxIts) {
  dt[csum>exclusionPeriod, diff := c(0, diff(start)), by = id]   
  dt[csum>exclusionPeriod, csum := cumsum(diff), by = id]
  its = its+1
}

out = dt[csum==0,.(id,start)]
print(out)
print(all.equal(modelOut,out))
```

Comment: I had to do something similar. The difficulty is the calculation is conditioned on the result of the calculation of the previous row, and so on. I feel this kind of thing has to be done by loop through rows. I had to do it through rcpp, which is extremely fast. Loop in cpp can handle thousands of rows in seconds.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50465590/i-need-a-loop-to-delete-rows-according-to-timestamp-difference-in-r/50479678#comment87985185_50479678

Comment: @chinsoon12, very helpful link. we could do `dt[, .SD[!deleteRow(start)], by = 'id']` to get desired `out`, after changing `x(i) - x(j) < 180` to `x(i) - x(j) < 5` in Roland's `deleteRow` function.