# Create a new column based on column that does not yet exist

Tags: r, data.table

I have the below data set:

```
DT <- fread("   df1 df2
  1   8
  2   9
  3  10
  4  11
  5  12")
```

I want to create a new column `df3` with first value equal to 100 and then `lag(df3, 1) * (1 + df2)`. So the final output will be:

```
df1 df2     df3
1  1  8     100
2  2  9    1000
3  3 10   11000
4  4 11  132000
5  5 12 1716000
```

I have tried running `DT[,df3 := lag(df3, 1) * (1 + df2)]` but because `df3`does not yet exists, so I get an error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm leaving previous answer below as it had some success, but I had overlooked that it would be much faster with `cumprod` :

```
DT$df3 <-  100 * cumprod(c(0,DT$df2[-1])+1)        # base R
DT[, df3:= 100 * cumprod(c(0,df2[-1])+1)]          # data.table
DT %>% mutate(df3 = 100 * cumprod(c(0,df2[-1])+1)) # tidyverse (only dplyr here)
```

We compute the cumulated product of `df2+1`, ignoring the first element and starting with `1`, and we multiply it by `100`.

---

*Previous answer with `Reduce`:*

This is a good job for `Reduce`, the function we're using is the simple multiplication, then we make sure to :

- add `1` to `df2` and ignore the first value.
- accumulate the results (`accumulate = TRUE`)

code:

```
DT$df3 <- Reduce(`*`,DT$df2[-1]+1,init = 100,accumulate = TRUE)
DT
#    df1 df2     df3
# 1:   1   8     100
# 2:   2   9    1000
# 3:   3  10   11000
# 4:   4  11  132000
# 5:   5  12 1716000
```

This works with base `R`, to use more idiomatic syntax with `data.table` one can follow @jogo's advice and write:

```
DT[, df3:=Reduce('*', df2[-1]+1, init = 100,accumulate = TRUE)]
```

And for completeness this would be the `tidyverse` way:

```
library(tidyverse)
DT %>% mutate(df3 = accumulate(df2[-1]+1,`*`,.init = 100))
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a C++ approach:

```
library(data.table)
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction(
  'NumericVector fun(const NumericVector x, const double y) {
     const double n = x.size();

     NumericVector res = NumericVector(n);
     res[0] = y;
     for (double i = 1; i < n; i++) {
       res[i] = res[i-1] * (x[i] + 1);
     }
     return res;
   }')

DT <- fread("   df1 df2
  1   8
  2   9
  3  10
  4  11
  5  12")

DT[, df3 := fun(df2, 100)]
# > DT
#    df1 df2     df3
# 1:   1   8     100
# 2:   2   9    1000
# 3:   3  10   11000
# 4:   4  11  132000
# 5:   5  12 1716000
```

---

comment: I am still learning C++. This function is based on another [C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50467707/3926543) written by Roland.

Comment: This is good to have these simple examples around, `rcpp` is probably very underused, seeing that it almost never comes up in benchmark competitions here on SO where it would probably often win. I've never taken the time to look into it myself...

Comment: An interesting approach! Many thnaks for your time